# Breaking RSA code

Tags: cryptography

I will be grateful for some tips on how to bite a task like so:
I need to break a RSA code. I know that public key is $n=462257, e=13$. I also have cryptogram $c=139552$. The goal is to find a number that is encrypted here.
I have written some things on wikipedia about RSA, but I am brand new on this area and I don't know how to even start.
What is $c$ for in this task? What steps should I take to find the answer?

Comment: Your task is to find a number $m$, the "message," such that $m^e\equiv c$ mod $n$.

Comment: Should we assume that we don't know, and can't compute that $503×919=462257$ or can we use that?

Comment: I think that we can assume what you have written

Comment: I'm a bit curious. What can anyone **write** about RSA on wikipedia, if this is a mystery?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The content of Wikipedia is supposed to come from sources. You don't have to know anything about a topic to write a whole article about it. Of course, knowing makes it easier, but not knowing is very far from being an impediment.

Comment: @Nathanson: Somebody here (Pete Clark?) told me that mathematical wikipedia-articles, at least those in English, have been checked by pros. If what you say is true, that does explain a few things I've seen (in my favorite tags and in Finnish :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I think the OP meant to say "read" instead of "written."

Comment: I hope so, @Barry. Sorry about sounding a bit. critical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by factoring $n = 462257 = 503 \cdot 919 $. You can calculate $\varphi(n)$ and $d$ now since you know that $d \equiv e^{-1} \pmod{\varphi(n)}$. Given $d$, you can decrypt $m$ as usual. Alternatively, use the method suggested by Barry Cipra in the comments (brute force $m^{13} \equiv 139552 \pmod{462257}$).

> You should get $m = 4242$.

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't suggesting a "method" in my comment beneath the OP, I was just addressing the question "What is $c$ for?"

Comment: It is very hard area for me. Thank you for the answer, even if I can't understand those things when I have tips ;)

Comment: @BarryCipra, sorry for misrepresenting you, I thought that you meant to simply bruteforce all values of $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the [cycling attack](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2834449/4280) for this case yields $m=4242$ after $1500$ steps in less than a second (small Python program).