# possible to decrypt RSA using these parameters only?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cryptography

If our **message is 204**, our **public RSA-key is (e, N) = (47, 221)** but the private key is unknown.

is it possible to retrieve the message without the private key and what would be the steps to do so?

Comment: In this case, couldn't you use the fact that $$N = 221 = 13 \times 17?$$

Comment: @Mo comments states that N = 13 * 17. I think I can calculate d using : e × d ≡ 1 (mod(12*16)) which comes out as d= 23. does this make sense?

Comment: I am not sure how you got that result for $d$, please recheck that. I get $d = 143$.

Comment: @Moo Now I can simply decrypt the message using 204^143 mod 221, right? Thank you for taking the time to help out!!

Comment: Were you told how the message was encoded? For example, one digit at time, two digits at a time,...?

Comment: @Moo I made the question up. Could be one digit at a time :)

Comment: Then, you would also decrypt one digit at a time - this is critical to do it both encoding and decoding using the same number of bits and also any methodology. So, you would do $$m_i = c_i^d \pmod {((p-1)(q-1))}$$ You would perform that operation three separate times to get back your message $m$.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your help and guiding me through this! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special situation you can easily test. In your case a private key is just the public key: 
$$204^{47} \equiv 68 \pmod {221}, \quad 68^{47} \equiv 204 \pmod {221}$$

The reason for this is, that $$47^{-1} \equiv 47 \pmod {\lambda(N)}$$
where $\lambda(N)$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). The often used private key via $\varphi(N)$ would be $d=143.$

Comment: Hmm I don't get. As @Moo comments states that N = 13 * 17. I think I can calculate d using : e × d ≡ 1 (mod(12*16)) which comes out as d= 23. Am i doing anything wrong here?

Comment: No, $47^{-1} \equiv 143 \pmod {192} $ where as your $23$ gives $23*47 \equiv 29 \pmod {192} $

Comment: Are you sure that $$23*47 \equiv 29 \pmod {192}$$

Comment: yes true, I made a silly mistake and calculated n = 13*7, sorry.. Now I can simply decrypt the message using 204^143 mod 221, right? Thank you for taking the time to help out!!

Comment: @moo: Yes you are wright, it is 121. I accidentally  computed 23*43. But the crucial point is that is $\not \equiv 1$.

Comment: @courtney-mill: Yes $d=143$ works, but as written, this is the normal private exponent found by factorization. $d=47$ **works too**, and the check 'is $d=e?$' can always be done, even for large $N.$ But normally this special case should be excluded during key generation.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your help and guiding me through this! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case the rather obscure [cycle attack](http://members.tripod.com/irish_ronan/rsa/attacks.html#cycle) works very well, by coincidence (or not; it's an exercise after all, with small parameters)

This works as follows: 
suppose the public key is $(N,e)$ and we receive the message $c$.
Then compute $c_0 = c, c_{n+1} = c^e \pmod{N}$ until $c = c_k$ for some $k \ge 1$ (this will always happen, only normally $k$ will be very large, but with small parameters its doable). Then $c_{k-1}$ is the original message (as its encryption is $c_k =c$).

Doing it here already gives $c_2 = 204$ and $c_1 = 68$ which is the plaintext.

[This paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0161-118891862891?journalCode=ucry20) explains why this is normally not a realistic attack in practice .